# MySQL field of type (byte) how to show it and "click to open"

Tags: java, mysql, swing

i have inserted and can retrieve the file (pdf, xls, png etc) with no problems but, i also wanted to show the "file" in a way that i could click on it to open (some component maybe). That is one thing.
Other is i also need to update a record that have this file in a column, for this part i have no solution yet but retrieve the file to insert it again.
So any suggestions would be very welcome.
I'm using MySQL, netbeans, the details of the records are displayed in a JTable.

```
 private void jBsalvarArquivoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    JFileChooser file = new JFileChooser();
    file.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    int i = file.showSaveDialog(null);
    if (i == 1) {

    } else {
        File arquivo = file.getSelectedFile();
        JtextFieldLocalArquivo.setText(arquivo.getPath());
         String path = arquivo.getPath();
    }
```

### }

here is when i insert the file along with the rest of the details

```
try {
        String newPath = path;
        FileInputStream input = null;

        File theFile = new File(newPath);

        input = new FileInputStream(theFile);

        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(input);
        condutorInfracao.setAnexoAuto(bytes);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File Not Loaded!");

    }
```

Update code (part of it):

```
   try {
        stmt = con.prepareStatement("Select * From responsabilidade where respons_descr = '" + (String) jCResponsabilidadeDescr.getSelectedItem() + "'");
        ResultSet r = null;
        r = stmt.executeQuery();
        List<Responsabilidade> objList = new ArrayList<Responsabilidade>();

        if (r.next()) {
            Responsabilidade obj = new Responsabilidade();
            obj.setResponsId(r.getInt("respons_id"));
            obj.setResponsDescr(r.getString("respons_descr"));

            objList.add(obj);
            condutorInfracao.setResponsabilidade(obj);
            r.close();
            stmt.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

i do it for all the fields then i have a DAO that does the update

```
 public void update() {
    try {
        transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
        sessao.update(param_set);
        transacao.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException erro) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Error!" +erro.getMessage());
        transacao.rollback();
    }

}
```

Comment: You'd have to download the file to the local disk and then you could use something like [`Desktop.open` or `Desktop.edit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html) to open the file within the system registered application.  You are right.  If you want to update the file, you will need to perform an `update` on the row in the database

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in this update i wanted to update the other fields, the field  "byte" i wanted to keep the file that already was saved. Not a new one, but even if i don't change the field "byte" when i click "update" for that row, the field "byte" is being updated to "empty"...

Comment: Where your update statement.?

Comment: I have updated the code above, but I think another question can give me a direction: how can i update some fields in a  row, and let others untouched? I think the problem can be the way i'm doing it...

Comment: Simply don't set the value for the field within an update statement...

Comment: That's what was doing ...But then i get something like : "null property references a null or transient value". So i started to set all the fields in the update. And that brought me to the question of " how keep old values in the record" for example a file in the field byte.

Comment: Where's the sql update command?

Comment: I have updated another part of my code.